# Can gitolite prevent branch deletes?

Tags: git-branch, gitolite

Is it possible to set up gitolite acls to allow a user to read, write, and push, but not to delete branches?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use as a general rule for all repositories:

```
repo @all
    RWCD dummy-branch = foo
```

The '`D`' is a "deletion" [type of permission](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/write-types.html), which will authorize the deletion of a `dummy-branch`, but will make all your *existing* `RW+` rule *deny* deletion (because they don't have a '`D`')