# git branch delete - HOOK

Tags: git, github, branch, hook

I have ready many articles about protecting remote branches...

I however would like to capture in a git hook the following LOCAL repo command:

```
git branch -d abranchthatshouldnotbedeleted
```

I would like to hook that command and analyze it against an branch list file of "protected branches" that I made and do a simple check to allow or deny the delete.

Certain branches of mine are now locked in a stated where they are managed now and must be protected.

Comment: What do you mean by "Certain branches of mine are now locked in a stated where they are managed now and must be protected."? Are you still able to make commits to the branches?

Answer (score 1):

Since GitHub [doesn't allow *pre*-receive hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864903/does-github-allow-pre-receive-hooks) (only [post-receive ones](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks)), I would recommend pushing to an *intermediate* local repo, protected by [Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) (an [authorization layer](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/auth.html), through ssh or http access to your git repo).

Gitolite can help code all kind of access rules, including [protecting a branch against deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13275736/6309).

If the push is allowed, then a post-commit hook can push that automatically to GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Git does not (currently) have a hook that you can use to do what you want.  See `git help hooks` for a list of available hooks.

You may want to consider a different approach.  For example, you could wrap `git` in a wrapper script or shell function that does its own parsing to prevent you from deleting the branch:

```sh
git() {
    [ "${1}" != branch ] ||
    { [ "$2" != -d ] && [ "$2" != -D ]; } ||
    case $3 in
        abranchthatshouldnotbedeleted) false;;
        *) true;;
    esac ||
    { printf %s\\n "ERROR: branch $3 must not be deleted" >&2; exit 1; }
    command git "$@"
}
```

The above shell function is quite primitive and doesn't handle invocations like `git --git-dir=/foo.git branch -d abranchthatshouldnotbedeleted`, but you get the point.  Perhaps you can use `git rev-parse --parseopt` to make it more robust.